# Search form on WordPress show results on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I have built our marketing pages on WordPress and I was hoping I could add a search form on the WordPress site and show the results on the Rails application. Could I use Elementor to build a form and on submit that info is sent to the rails application to show the results from the rails DB and the user will now be on the rails application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about a form that is hosted on a Wordpress instance, which submits to a Rails app.  While in general you could set the form action to post to any server, you will have problems doing this with Rails specifically because of the form authenticity_token, which is required by default for Rails forms with POST method.
[See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html)

One way to stop Rails from doing this is to disable request forgery protection in your Rails controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Another approach could be to build the search form in your Rails app, and embed it in an iFrame on your Wordpress.  After the form is submitted in the iframe, you can redirect_to the results from the Rails controller, which will break out of the iframe with a HTTP 302 response that sets the user's browser location to the Rails application's results page.